# How to get ip address of client connected to remote desktop

Tags: php, remote-desktop

i need to retrieve the ip address of the client that is connected through remote desktop to a windows server.

i need to get it possibly through php.

So client connects to remote desktop and run from browser a php page that is on the server which client is connected.

If i run `print_r($_SERVER)` i get:

```
Array (
...
[HTTP_HOST] => 10.80.3.107 //This is server ip
...
[SERVER_NAME] => 10.80.3.107 //This is server ip
[SERVER_ADDR] => 10.80.3.107 //This is server ip
[SERVER_PORT] => 80
[REMOTE_ADDR] => 10.80.3.107 //This is server ip -> I need client ip here
...
)
```

Is there any solution?

can i use cmd to get that info and than take it from php using exec?

I can't use `netstat -n | find ":3389" | find "ESTABLISHED"` because it gives me all client connected and not only the one i need.

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot get the information from a client that is connecting to the same machine as the server. You should add a plugin or something to the browser that appends a HTTP header with info to distinguish your users (using client-sided information, like username).

Comment: i can use %clientname% env-path. From cmd it gives me the correct value but from php it gives me "box". With client name using php i can retrieve ip adress..

Comment: That's because PHP is run on the server side (in this case, the same system). It still uses the user the server is started with (prolly the deamon user name). Now that I think of it, you can call `php.exe` to do stuff for you (under the logged-in user)... Why do you want to get the user again? Isn't a login page suffice?

Comment: i tried to execute php.exe launching another script that takes %clientname% from exec in php and it gives me the same results..

Comment: When you call php.exe from commandline, you can give it arguments. Could you try that?

Comment: i give it just the path of php file that takes the clientname info

Comment: Yes, but you can pass arguments to the application (for the PHP file) that you can read using `$argv`, like `php.exe -f yourphpfile.php '%clientname%'`

Comment: it continue giving me "box" and not the real clientname

Comment: Do people have their own credentials for logging into the box? That way, %UserName% shows their name, I gues... No IP, tho. Maybe you need to quickly check the eventlog and get the last succeeded login, and use info from that... `\(O.o)/`

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve by using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] or $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] variables of PHP.

The below both functions are equivalent with the difference only in how and from where the values are retrieved.

In first function have used getenv() is used to get the value of an environment variable in PHP

// Function to get the client ip address using getenv() function

```
    function get_client_ipaddress() {
     $ip_address = '';
     if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
         $ip_address = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
     else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
         $ip_address = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'&quot;);
     else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
         $ip_address = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
     else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
         $ip_address = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
     else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
        $ip_address = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
     else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
         $ip_address = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
     else
         $ip_address = 'UNKNOWN';

     return $ip_address; 
}
```

Without using getenv() function:

```
    function get_client_ipaddress() {
     $ip_address = '';
     if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
         $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
     else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
         $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
     else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
         $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
     else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
         $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
     else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
         $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
     else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
         $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
     else
         $ip_address = 'UNKNOWN';

     return $ip_address; 
}
```